# Swift: How to iterate through an array of instances of generic class

Tags: swift

I have a class:

```swift
class MyClass<T> {
    func whoAreYou() {
        print("I am \(T.self)")
    }
}
```

I created two instances:

```swift
let a = MyClass<Int>()
let b = MyClass<Double>()
```

I want to put them in an array and iterate through them, but I was failed to do it. I tried:

```swift
// not working
let objects: [MyClass<Any>] = [a as! MyClass<Any>, b as! MyClass<Any>]
for object in objects {
    object.whoAreYou()
}
```

I also tried:

```swift
// not working
for object in [a, b] {
    object.whoAreYou()
}
```

Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: Define "not working". In what way exactly isn't your code working? Update your question with specific detail such as error messages if any.

Comment: This is where you realize the power of protocols. :)

Comment: You seem to think generics are polymorphic — technically, that they are covariant on the parameterized type. They are not. So `MyClass<Any>` does not somehow embrace `MyClass<Int>`. They are different types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work if you create a protocol, like this:

```
protocol Identifiable {
    func whoAreYou()
}
```

Then, conform your class to your created protocol:

```
class MyClass<T>: Identifiable {
    func whoAreYou() {
        print("I am \(T.self)")
    }
}
```

Create the instances of your class:

```
let a = MyClass<Int>()
let b = MyClass<Double>()
```

Later in your code:

```
for object in [a, b] as [Identifiable] {
    object.whoAreYou()
}
```

Or this:

```
let objects: [Identifiable] = [a, b]

for object in objects {
    object.whoAreYou()
}
```